# What is the best choice of format/package for including an animation into a powerdot presentation?

Tags: animations, powerdot

Me again :-(

System: Windows 7, MikTeX 2.9, WinEdt 7, LaTeX->Dvips->ps2pdf pipe

Trying [the same animation as a year ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148430/9446) - just for the sake of being specific. This year I am teaching multivariable calculus so my needs will be a bit different, and this time I am aiming a bit higher.

Below you can see one animation I want to embed to a PowerDot presentation

[image]

It is 64 frames of GIF. Filesize about 150 kB. As we all know we cannot mix .gif and .eps (sigh), so something has to give. The animation is generated by Mathematica, so I have the options of exportin it (as well as individual frames) at least  in .eps, .gif, .swf, .avi, .png formats.

Last year I managed using *media9*. That package is good for many a thing, but to use it I needed to convert the animation to either .swf or .mp4. And that's were the problems lie. Try as I may I was unable to get the conversion to keep the video quality. Hardly a surprise as neither of those formats is designed with compressing mathematical plots in mind. The avi-file has size 10MB at this quality, but both the swf and mp4 look cruddy in comparison - the curves look like they were first anti-aliased to 160x100 screen resolution and left at that with all the jaggies (your eyes are spared, because we cannot embed an mp4 to a question). The conversion service linked to in the previous question cannot be coerced to do lossless compression. To tell you the truth I don't know if there is anything like lossless mp4?

> Are there options other than media9? This is only 64 frames (and I can compromise with a lower number). Or can you recommend a conversion program that produces higher quality mp4s from this kind of frames.

Will using the animate package help? Will that necessitate each frame to come from a separate file or can it handle an animated GIF?

Comment: The number of frames is relatively small. The best result in terms of quality and scalability might be obtained with animating a set of vector graphics using the `animate` package. Can you direct Mathematica to produce vector graphics (in EPS format, as required by Powerdot)?

Comment: This seems to be [possible](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/EPS.html).

Comment: Yes. That is possible. I probably need to figure out how to name the files with the frame number tagged to the end, but that should not be too taxing. Will using `animate` package allow LaTeX to output everything in a single pdf-file?

Comment: Yes, at the end you will get your presentation PDF with embedded animations for display with AdobeReader.

Comment: Great. So I just need to study [animate manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf). Shouldn't be too difficult. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexG. That worked. I had [minor difficulties getting my MikTeX installation to use the updated Ghostscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214616/9446), but everything seems to be fine now.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to warn you about this requirement. Glad to hear that it works now.

Comment: I have just seen that, in powerdot, animation controls are rotated by 90 deg. I will be uploading an update very soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by AlexG the package *animate* works very well here. Posting a summary of the steps as an answer in case somebody later has the same problem. The early steps include Mathematica instructions, which may be off-topic here, but I needed to get it to co-operate with LaTeX, so hopefully that is ok.

1. Prepare the individual frames as separate eps-files. I had coded a Mathematica function `roll[t_]` that produced the image of a rolling circle that had revolved a total angle `t` together with the part of the cycloid drawn up to that point. For the animation to work as intended it is probably a good idea to set the `PlotRange` -option so that the entire area is shown - your call.
2. Save the files so that their filenames end with the frame number as instructed in the *animate* manual. I did it with the following command that produced 65 files named "sykloidi0.eps", sykloidi1.eps", et cetera
   `For[k = 0, k < 65, ++k, 
    Export[StringJoin[{"sykloidi", ToString[k], ".eps"}], roll[k*0.1]]]`
3. In the above step you may need to cut down the size of the created eps-images. The reason is that the animate-package has problems fitting oversized images correctly into the pdf-animation. The solution is to give Export an extra parameter `ImageSize->150`or another suitable value. Otherwise you may run into difficulties described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225808/9446).
4. In your TeX-source add the following line. Pick options to your liking.

   `\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,width=320pt,height=100pt,keepaspectratio]{12}{sykloidi}{0}{64}`

Comment: Thank you for this nice tutorial! However, zero-padding the numbers in the filenames (step 3) is really not necessary. Simple numbers work perfectly too: `\animategraphics[...]{12}{sykloidi}{0}{64}` .